# how to uninstall .NET Framework 4.8 from windows 11

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

Problem
I've some commercial app to be runned on my system which couldn't work so their tech
team wants me to uninstall & reinstall .Net Framework. So, I did uninstall all .Net
related files through program & feature.
But, I still get an error that ".NET Framework 4.8 or later update is already installed
on this while reinstalling new .NETFRAME 4.8     computer.

What I've tried

1. I've uninstall all .Net related app such as Visual studio VS code. there nothing left
2. Ensure that unchecked .Net framework related features in TURN WINDOWS FEATURE - Program & Feature. I also tried "checked".Net framework related features but same problem occured

I went across STACK "How to remove .NET framework" solution from Aaron stebner, I'm not sure it would work as it is all about .NET 4.6

Solution I need:

I JUST WANT to WIPE OUT ALL .NETFRAME files, so I could be able to reinstall .NETFRAME 4.8 again on Windows 11